# concurrent table update

Tags: oracle

Does following update query always leave table data unchanged?

```
update mytable set column1 = column1
```

Wonder if there will be lost updates?

Initially `column1` has value `oldValue`. There are two transactions (t1 and t2) and t2 starts in the middle of t1.

```
t1: update mytable set column1 = 'newValue'
```

and

```
t2: update mytable set column1 = column1
```

as t2 transaction started later than t1 it also finished later than t1.

The question: what value will be assigned to the `column1`?

Comment: Oh, had to check before asking. The second transaction is blocked until the first is committed or rolled back. So I assume the answer is such query never changes a table data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction isolation level is what to isolate different transactions, and if you use read committed or higher isolation levels, there won't be any problem.

By the way as far as I know your first query never updates any record in Oracle, even with "read uncommitted" isolation level.